# Issue in converting to list from dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have already converted my dictionary to a list but got stuck in getting in specific format. My output dictionary is,

```
foldersinlist = [['Training'], ['Training videos', 'Training documents', 'Training workouts', 'Training practicals', 'Training practicals', 'Training practicals']]
```

How I want is,

```
['Training', 'Training videos', 'Training documents', 'Training workouts', 'Training practicals', 'Training practicals', 'Training practicals']
```

The code which I currently have is below,

```
foldersinlist = list(folders.values())
print(foldersinlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
print([x for i in foldersinlist for x in i])
```

Output:

```
['Training', 'Training videos', 'Training documents', 'Training workouts', 'Training practicals', 'Training practicals', 'Training practicals']
```

Answer (score 0):

this is nested list and not dictionary:

```
foldersinlist = [['Training'], ['Training videos', 'Training documents', 'Training workouts', 'Training practicals', 'Training practicals', 'Training practicals']]
```

this is flat list:

```
['Training', 'Training videos', 'Training documents', 'Training workouts', 'Training practicals', 'Training practicals', 'Training practicals']
```

just do:

```
ll = sum(foldersinlist , [])
```